# CSS: can I hide the borders of the searchbox?

Tags: css

Can I hide the borders of the searchbox ? I would like it completely white, just the text should be visible.  And I need a solution for all browsers.

See the picture:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/searchBox.png

Comment: ... search box. I made a mistake and got 5 answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" class="hide_border" id="textfield" />
```

css

```
.hide_border{
    border:none;
    *border:solid 1px #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a standard checkbox I am not sure whether you get this effect in a cross browser way. You can use a custom element and make it act like a checkbox using CSS and javascript.

See this one which uses jquery

**[Fancy custom radio and checkbox](http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Why don't you just hide the checkbox and leave the label ? (Later using javascript and such you can redisplay the checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes can not be styled in all browsers. The common solution is to use two images, toggling between the two when clicked (and updating a hidden field as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Styling checkboxes isn't doable in a crossbrowser fashion without some jQuery, have a look at this: [Custom checkboxes with jQuery](http://john.mcclumpha.org/javascript/Creating_custom_styled_checkboxes_with_jQuery/). It's the only way to do it, standard checkboxes cannot be styled in all browsers.

Comment: The "only way to do it" is jQuery? Really?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.inputsearch input
{
   background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}
</style>


<div class="inputsearch" style="text-align:left;">
  <input type="text" value="HEy there ">
</div>
```